# Use 'javax.swing.Timer' and 'java.util.Timer' in the same project?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a Tetris project and I am finding that I need to use both **javax.swing.Timer** and **java.util.Timer**. But one of them is not working. Can anyone provide any insight into this problem?

Comment: yes you can, what was it that did not work?

Comment: If you want to use them in the same file, you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the 2 classes together but you have to enter the full package like this

```
java.util.Timer myUtilTimer= ..
javax.swing.Timer  myUtilTimer= ..
```

Besides you have to take care that output from `java.util.Timer` must be wrapped into `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(myRunnable);` to add to the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) otherwise is no guaranted that anything should be diplayed/changed/repainted

Comment: I agree with @AndrewThompson, but because you fixed it, +1 from me.

Comment: You're welcome.  Since I'm here, I deleted some noise (the old comments).

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can use 2 classes with the same name, but rather than importing them, you should use the full qualifier:

ie:

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but if you are using both in the same java file, you will need to access one of the class by the full package name like `java.util.Timer` because it will get a conflict if you import both of the classes.

Answer (score 1):

In this concrete [example](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.java.gui/sWKy5Oo8s3E/ndTrL9u85vYJ), "A `javax.swing.Timer` increments  an `int` at 
100 Hz, while a `java.util.TimerTask` samples the value at 1 Hz." A `LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>` synchronizes access to the shared data and records the last `N` samples. The example illustrates features of all three preceding answers:

- Use of a fully qualified name.
- Use of `invokeLater()`.